# Selecting XML Elements using Index

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq-to-xml

I have XML file in the following format;

```
<root>

<entry>
<details>
</entry>

<entry>
<details>
</entry>
...
</root>
```

I don't have any attributes and I display the details field in a ListBox control which allows copying and deleting items.

So, if the user deletes the second entry in the listbox, second entry in the xml file needs to be deleted completely.

Is there a way to do this ?

Currently, I'm using Linq-to-XML for writing the data.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention the selection mode of the ListBox - it's MultiExtended.

Comment: Sorry, it took some time to check this...I'm checking out the code as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's simple code to load, remove the indexed entry and then save the file.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
root.Elements("entry").ElementAt(index).Remove();
root.Save(file);
```

To match multiple:

```
int[] match = new int[] { 1, 10, 25, 33 };
var matches = root.Elements("entry").Where((x, i) => match.Contains(i));
foreach (var e in matches.ToList()) e.Remove();
```

Comment: Will this work for multiple elements ? I'm getting some unexpected results.

Comment: The unexpected probably comes because what you are displaying no longer matches the list.  What you need to do, before any are removed is match them by index and then remove them all at once.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very loose definition, but the following ought to work:

```
// untested
var entries = xDoc.Root.Elements("entry").ToList();
entries[selectedIndex].Remove();
xDoc.Save(...);
```

Comment: Will this work for multiple elements ? I'm getting some unexpected results.